How to use a js library inside t-name template in odoo
I am trying to use a multiselection library inside a template (<t t-name=...) rendered by qweb.render.
the library works fine in home page (<template id=...), but it won't work in <t t-name=...
enter image description here
i am using odoo 15 community
Can any one help me with this.
Best regards
i ve called the .js and .css files of the library in web.assets_frontend.

the Not working code:

<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="t_lead_form">
        <select multiple="multiple" name="language" class="b_multiselection">
              <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
              <option value="html">HTML</option>
              <option value="css">CSS</option>
            </select>
    </t>
</templates>


The working code:

<template id="createFormModal">
<select multiple="multiple" name="language" class="b_multiselection">
                                  <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
                                  <option value="html">HTML</option>
                                  <option value="css">CSS</option>
                                </select>
</template>


You can specify the CDN of the javascript library inside the manifest under the bundle  web.assets_frontend and then use the class name 'b_multiselection' as it is now.

yes i did
'web.assets_frontend': [
'my_project/static/src/libs/multirange/jquery.nstSlider.min.css',
'my_project/static/src/libs/multirange/jquery.nstSlider.min.js',
],
and as i said in the description it worked fine in 

For that you should load it along with the second template's asset bundle.

The frontend asset bundle is about all that is specific to the public website: e-commerce, portal, forum, blog. To use in the backend and frontend, try to load it to the common asset bundle (web.assets_common)
